# The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.Windows server 2016

Tags: c#, windows, sqlconnection

On new windows server 2016 we are getting exception when wcf service is trying to connection the database (sql server 2017) using entity framework. The same code is working on number of machines.

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.  errordetails~ExceptionMessage - The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception. 
ExceptionSource - System.Data  
ExceptionTarget - Void .ctor()  
StackTrace - System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Common.ADP' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.VerificationException: Method System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange: type argument 'System.Data.Res' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TException'.
   at System.Data.Res.GetLoader()
   at System.Data.Res.GetString(String name)
   at System.Data.Common.ADP..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters..ctor(String categoryName, String categoryHelp)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.CreateConnection()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetStoreConnection(DbProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
   at EntityDataAccessLayer.dbConnString..ctor()
```

The full list of inner exceptions at the top:

> StackTrace - System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Common.ADP' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.VerificationException: Method System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange: type argument 'System.Data.Res' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TException'.

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: Type initialiser exceptions indicate that a static constructor threw. If this is from a framework type I would start by repairing the .NET Framework install on the machine.

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: ExceptionMessage - The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception. 
ExceptionSource - System.Data  
ExceptionTarget - Void .ctor()

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=DBServer;Initial Catalog=abcd;User ID=abcd;Password=abcd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

the final error is: `type argument 'System.Data.Res' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TException'`, which means: it tried to call function with a parameter, but the function does not support it, in the other hand, it means: an overload or update is lost, so versions got mismatch in base framework.

you have options for figure it out:

1. Debug on source code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2017
2. Enable `Funsion Log` to get assembly info to check mismatch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer
3. Run [dotnet command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21) to check out what versions are referenced by your project, some assemblies are using higher versions if not strictly configured.

The issue is similar with these 2 posts:

1. https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/issues/425
2. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18406

It happens a lot when versions got mismatch.

You can try to upgrade all related packages, including frameworks itself.

If the core library `System.Data.SqlClient` is too old to match latest versions of other packages, then you have to downgrade other packages that are in your project.

Comment: No issues with versions, as same is working on another server with same configurations.

Comment: @Simplyvaibh hardly to figure it out without the environment. but enable `fusion log` could help you immediately find out where is real issue. answer updated.